# Accessing object variables by class name instead of this

Tags: java, instance-variables

Usually when there is getter/setter in a POJO class, the general convention I have seen until now was to use `return this.<instance variable>` / `this.<instance variable> = something`

But, the current project I am working on uses a strange convention of `return <class name>.<instance variable>`

I understand that this works, but was wondering if this is the right approach at all?

Comment: `<class name>.<instance variable>` is static variable?

Comment: No. These are instance variables

Comment: @Sara That makes no sense. Instance variables are associated *with instances*, not the class themselves

Comment: @BingLi224 no. These are instance variables.

Comment: Its better if you post some code??

Comment: Sure it's not `<class name>.this.<instance variable>`?

Comment: *no. These are instance variables.* If you are so adamant, please show your code

Comment: your variable might be static.

Answer (score -2):

You have to make that variable or method static then you can use through class name.

```
public static int a=5;
/*declaring static variable*/



  System.out.println(classname.a);
  /*calling static variable*/
```